# is it possible to direct connect a client and server with 10GBASE CX4 copper cables?

Tags: networking, sas, cable, 10gbethernet, 10gige

Server has two 10GBASE-CX4 ports.
client has 10GBASE CX4 HBA.

can theybe directly connected with a CX4 cable without the need for a switch? like SAS Infiband connectors?

Comment: You keep asking the same questions over and over again.

Comment: i dont intend to ask same questions. since i bought the CX4 hardware and looking for a switch someone told be direct access using cable is possible for 1-1 and can save the cost of 10G switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works perfectly fine without a switch. Give each system an IP on the same subnet.

I've run this setup with dual-port Intel CX4 10GbE cards between a VMware host server and a Sun x4540 storage unit.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your NICs support auto-MDIX. I *think* it is a required part of the 10GE standard but I couldn't verify that.