# Direct connect (peer to peer) two servers with 10GbE SPF+ ports?

Tags: networking, gigabit

Someone asked earlier whether it would be possible to direct connect two systems with 10GbE CX4 ports here: [is it possible to direct connect a client and server with 10GBASE CX4 copper cables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217311).

My question is the same, but with the SPF+ ports.  I assume this would work, but before ordering the pricey interconnect cable, I thought of confirming whether it is at least likely that it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make sure you're getting SPF+ direct connects and that your cards support that configuration.

<sub>Some exclusions apply. See dealer for complete rules, full details, and restriction. Your millage may vary. Slippery when wet.</sub>