# Peer to peer connection over SFP+ Passive 10Gbe cable

Tags: linux, networking, network-attached-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to direct connect a client and server with 10GBASE CX4 copper cables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217311/is-it-possible-to-direct-connect-a-client-and-server-with-10gbase-cx4-copper-cab)

I am attempting to create a peer-to-peer connection between two machines like the guy mentioned here: [is it possible to direct connect a client and server with 10GBASE CX4 copper cables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217311/is-it-possible-to-direct-connect-a-client-and-server-with-10gbase-cx4-copper-cab)

I have these cables from the server vendor 
http://www.provantage.com/supermicro-cbl-0347l~7SUP92HM.htm

Will these work without a switch in between? Obviously I am assuming that 10Gbe is similar to normal ethernet in that the cables require a pass-over style wiring inside the cable. If that is true please give me a heads up as well.

Comment: Not sure how it could be a dupe as the cabling is different in both questions (at least to my intermediate knowledge) but hopefully someone here knows better than me since that is why I am asking.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a duplicate. It's asking about SFP, not copper. While the answer may apply to both, that fact is a technical detail that should be stated in the answer to this question. [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/426869/10gbe-sfp-cross-over-cable-required-is-there-such-a-thing) provides a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will work just fine. Which 10GbE HBAs will you be using?

Comment: On one end I will have this adapter: Intel® 82599EB 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller with 2 SFP+ interfaces on the other end I will have any of these three depending on what comes back as the best one for the job: Intel X520-DA2 (E10G42BTDA), Emulex OCe11102-IX or Emulex OCe11102-NX