# 10gb ethernet direct connection (no switch)

Tags: ethernet, 10gbethernet

Im trying to connect 2 computers with 2 PCIe

"Core 4 HP 671798-001 HP CX-2 NIC 1 PORT 10GB"

I'm using a SFP+ Direct Attach Copper Cable (I think they are also called twinax)

I found a similar question in the site but it is not answering if it should work or not, and the answers vaguely say that DCE and DTE does not apply to these devices therefore crossover is not needed, but the wikipedia page for SFP says that they do have RD and TD (RD on pins 12-13 and TD on 18-19)
I don't have a 10GB switch, I'm just trying to connect the 2 computers using 10GB link between them.

I have installed them in two Windows server 2012 computers and installed the required drivers.
Once they are connected, the lights on the adapters will not light up showing active connection and the adapters (in windows) show as "unplugged"

Should they lit up?

Should this configuration work?

Do I need some kind of crossover (if they even exist for this)?

Is my only option a super expensive switch?
I have a cisco switch that has 2 SFP but they are 1G so I didn't even try to connect them to it.

Thank you

Comment: Did you see http://serverfault.com/questions/426869/10gbe-sfp-cross-over-cable-required-is-there-such-a-thing ? Sounds like this should work.